# Mute all notification sound except Call Message and WhatsApp to be on Vibration Mode

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, calls, silent-mode, custom-sounds

I have a brand new Galaxy S10. I would like to keep the phone in mute mode but want the phone to vibrate if there is any Call, SMS or any WhatsApp notification.

How to do this? I do not wish to root the phone as of now.

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/88633/lollipop-mute-notifications-but-not-calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the easiest way to accomplish this is through do not disturb mode with custom exceptions.

Allowing calls and text messages through do not disturb mode is easy. Simply set "Calls from" and "Messages from" to "All" on the "allow exceptions" menu under the do no disturb settings.

For other apps, such as Whatsapp, you can do the following:

1. Enable do not disturb mode.
2. Go to Settings > Notifications.
3. Select the app you would like to modify.
4. Select the type of notification you would like to exclude from do not disturb mode, such as message notifications.
5. Enable the "Ignore Do not disturb" switch.
6. Back out of this screen and repeat steps 3-5 until your notifications are configured as you desire.

Comment: Unfortunately, this don't work in miui. So you have to install an app like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=co.easy4u.ncleaner) to block all notifications manually. I don't know any way to block sound only though

Answer (score -2):

*go to settings*
*and search for sounds in that ,there will be the  different options like different settings for sounds in that you can find your favour application and make it your wish *